# How to open the "File Browse" dialog from PyQGIS plugin code?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am in the process of developing a plugin for QGIS using Python. Note that this is my first plugin, so the query could be quite basic...

I have used [this Digital Geography link](http://www.digital-geography.com/build-qgis-plugin/#.VCkICGeSwsE) to create the basic plugin, and (quite surprisingly found it easy) created the plugin files.

I am stuck at a very basic concept. Previously, while using Python IDLE, using

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Input, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.OpenBrowse)
```

to signal a click and writing a function OpenBrowse

```
    def OpenBrowse(self):
        self.Input_TB.setText(filename1)
```

I was able to open the Windows File Browse window on click and set the File location to an adjoining text box.

**How do I do this while developing the plugin in the Python file that is created by Plugin Builder.?** I am very confused about where should the code be written? Because if I place the 'clicked()' actions, etc. in the Python file generated from the UI file, it is not recognizing the variables as they are not global (obviously).

I am using QGIS 2.4, on a Windows 32-bit system.

Answer (score 3):

Let us imagine your UI file name is MyDialogFile.py. Then,

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog
from MyDialogFile import MyDialog 

def InitGui(self):
    #other stuff....
    self.dialog = MyDialog()    

def OpenBrowse(self):        
    filename1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    self.dialog.Input_TB.setText(filename1)
```

Comment: This works in a normal IDLE program. The difference with that and PyQGIS is that the UI commands are in a different file and the actual tool execution program is in a different file. This does not work in this setup of PyQGIS. No errors, but just doesn't do what's needed..

Comment: @Akhil - mmm...i think you should import the UI file into the tool execution .py file..something like, from MyDialogFile import MyDialog

Comment: @Akhil - Updated my answer. you could look at some of the existing qgis plugins, like QuickWkt Plugin for example to see how it connects to UI, https://github.com/elpaso/quickwkt

Answer (score 2):

Modifications need to be made in 3 different files in the folder generated by Plugin Builder...

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Input, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.OpenBrowse)
```

To be added in the **UI File** under the main Class...

```
def OpenBrowse(self):        
    filename1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    self.dialog.Input_TB.setText(filename1)
```

**Function** to be defined in the **'plugin_class_name'dialog.py** file

and

```
self.dialog = Ui_'Class_Name'()
```

in the main plugin **python script** under the **initGui()** function...